# Visibility Rule Not Working in Media Queries

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, media-queries, media

I have the following code in my _header.html.erb

```
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Brand </a>
```

I want this to display on mobile but not on large displays...

I have:

```
.navbar-brand {
     visibility:hidden;
}
```

in my general css.

I use media queries to counter the above code, but not successfully.

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {
    .navbar-brand{
         visibility:visible;
    }
}
```

The result is that, the **brand** shows up no-where.

The code above is intended to target an iPhone5.  Is it possible that other devices have the same a-r and the display won't be shown?  Or is the above @media an appropriate way to accomplish what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise using width for media query to target phones, if your okay with a person minimizing the browser's width and seeing the same result

```
.navbar-brand {
    display: block;
}

@media only screen 
and (max-width : 321px) {
.navbar-brand {
    display: none;
}
```

And yes it is possible other devices have the same ratio. Specifying this way is troublesome from my experience, and I advise the way above. If you really want to target a specific device, do a quick script check for user agent string of the specific device and load css special for that device below your regular css.

Comment: visibility not changing in either @media query

Comment: With visibility it will be the exact same as display http://jsfiddle.net/67WJN/7/

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, if you have two rules that target the same element, there are a number of factors that control which one applies. The two that matter to us are *specificity* and *order*.

*Specificity* means "which rule is more specific?". Consider this HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
div p { 
    color: red;
}

p { 
    color: blue;
}
```

In this case, the text will be red. `div p` is a *more specific* selector, so that rule overrides the red text set by the `p` selector.

If two rules have the same specificity, then the *order* comes into play. Later rules have precedence. Let's change our CSS above to the following:

```
div p { 
    color: red;
}

p { 
    color: blue;
} 

div p { 
    color: green;
}
```

Now we have two rules with the same specificity. The last one will apply, so our text will be green.

---

So how does this relate to your problem? In two ways:

1. **Media queries don't increase specificity.**
2. **The Rails asset pipeline can change your CSS ordering.**

If your mobile CSS is included in the same file as your desktop styles, make sure it's at the bottom of your file, so your mobile rules override your global rules above. And if you're putting it in a separate file, you're going to have to list all of your CSS files in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` and put your `mobile.css` at the very bottom of your `//= require` rules, so it gets loaded after all the others. If you allow the Rails `//= require_tree .` to include your mobile stylesheet, the order will be undefined (but is almost always alphabetical). Which means that your mobile rules won't apply if they're trying to override something in a file starting with something from the second half of the alphabet. Your un-media-queried rules will override the media queried ones.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old, but the answer for me was slightly different, and while I don't like my answer as I try to avoid using (!important) when possible, the only thing that worked for me currently was to add !important after my desired visibility setting in the media query.

```css
.menuNavDropdown {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```